# Unresolved import `core::array::FixedSizeArray`

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust.
I've been given some Rust code to work with but the cargo build fails with error "unresolved import `core::array::FixedSizeArray`". In what way can I remove the error?

I'm using version 1.57.0 nightly; do not know which version of Rust the code base has been build successfully last time.

The code also uses a lot of '#![feature(...)]', which could not be used with stable version. How do I map a feature in older version's nightly build to the current version's functions/etc.?
Example of features:
#![feature(vec_resize_default)]
#![feature(fixed_size_array)]

Thanks.

Comment: It is removed in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/84094
How to fix the error depends on how it is used in your code

Comment: Based on the timing, around version 1.51.0 would be the latest one with that trait. If you've decided on using nightly, you'd typically lock yourself to a specific version via an [override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) if you're not interested in fixing things that break between versions. If you want to update to a newer version because of newer features, then you'll have to embrace and fix the changes; there's no way to just use removed features on a newer version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dawer: I suppose if a piece of code uses anything provided FixedSizeArray, there will be something like FixedSizeArray::etc. or FixedSizeArray.fetc(). other than the 'use core::array::FixedSizeArray' line.
What I'd like to know is where the functionalities of the FixedSizeArray has possibly gone; and if there is any pointer for me to explore myself of Rust-lang's evolution trace.

Answer (score 2):

The last version with [`FixedSizeArray`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.52.0/core/array/trait.FixedSizeArray.html) was the 1.52.1 release. It was designed for generically working with fixed size arrays `[T; N]` in contexts where `&[T]` or `AsRef<[T]>` were not appropriate. But even in the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27778) it is known that its usefulness was limited and would eventually be overshadowed by [`min_const_generics`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74878) which was just made stable in the 1.51.0 release.

You will have to either downgrade your nightly version back to 1.52.1 or before, or fix the problems caused by its removal. There is no way to just use removed features on a newer version.

Some options for replacing this functionality:

1. It can be translated directly into the form `[T; N]` using const generics.

   ```
   struct MyStruct<A: FixedSizeArray> {
       data: A
   }

   fn make_my_struct<A: FixedSizeArray>(data: A) -> MyStruct<A> {
       MyStruct { data }
   }
   ```

   Would become:

   ```
   struct MyStruct<T, const N: usize> {
       data: [T; N]
   }

   fn make_my_struct<T, const N: usize>(data: [T; N]) -> MyStruct<T, N> {
       MyStruct { data }
   }
   ```
2. Perhaps you didn't need it in the first place and can get by with just `&[T]` or `AsRef<[T]>`.
3. Use a trait from a crate that has a similar purpose like [`Array`](https://docs.rs/array_ext/0.3.0/array_ext/trait.Array.html) from the [`array_ext`](https://crates.io/crates/array_ext) crate.
4. Make your own trait. `FixedSizeArray` doesn't require any compiler magic, but to implement it for all array types you'd have to use method #1 above anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I "translated" a trait bound using FixedSizeArray like so:

old:

```
U: FixedSizeArray<T>
```

new:

```
U: AsRef<[T]> + AsMut<[T]>>
```